# Script to automatically decrease a cell value by the same amount as another cells increase

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, triggers, eventtrigger

how would i automatically decrease a cells value by the same amount as another cells increase. Cell A1s value is not input manually it is a Sum formula. some examples bellow.

If cell W6 increases by x# then automatically decrease cell S6 by the same number unless S6=0.

Say W6=1 & S6=5 and i add 2 too W6 i want S6 to change from 5 too 3 unless S6=0 then do nothing.

W6 ↑ 1 then S6 ↓ 1 unless S6=0 then stop.

I was fooling around with on onEdit trying to make it work. but I am not the best at scripts. it seems like a fairly easy thing to do but it is beyond me.

Comment: There are no triggers to capture this type of change.

Comment: A change in a formula does not cause onEdit to trigger.  And there is no way of knowing the value before the formula changed.  What causes the formula to change value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why not just include a subtraction formula in the cell? on S6 =IF(*whatever formula you have there* - W6 < 0,*whatever formula you have there*,*whatever formula you have there* - W6)